Global typeConverter using @automapper/nestjs
Is it possible to create global typeConverters with automapper for NestJS?
For example if I always want to convert Date into string (Model -> DTO) and string into Date (DTO -> Model).
The only solution I currently found is adding typeConverters to every profile:
typeConverter(String, Date, (str) => new Date(str))

Used versions:
"@automapper/classes": "^8.8.1",
"@automapper/core": "^8.8.1",
"@automapper/nestjs": "^8.8.1",

Edit: I implemented a workaround solution by creating an abstract BaseProfile and other profiles are extending this instead of AutomapperProfile:
import { MappingConfiguration, typeConverter } from '@automapper/core';
import { AutomapperProfile } from '@automapper/nestjs';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BigNumber } from 'ethers';

@Injectable()
export abstract class BaseProfile extends AutomapperProfile {
  /**
   * This contains mapping configs which are global.
   * (This is a workaround since it's not possible to define e.g. global typeConverters )
   * @protected
   */
  protected get mappingConfigurations(): MappingConfiguration[] {
    return [
      typeConverter(BigNumber, String, bigNumber =>
        bigNumber ? bigNumber.toString() : undefined,
      ),
      typeConverter(String, BigNumber, bigNumberAsString =>
        bigNumberAsString ? BigNumber.from(bigNumberAsString) : undefined,
      ),
    ];
  }
}

